# Question about uniform integrability of a collection of measurable fucntions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, uniform-integrability

I am reading uniform integrability and it is defined as below
Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\nu)$ be a finite measurable space and $F$=$f_{\alpha}\colon\Omega \to R$ (measurable) where $\alpha\in I$} then $F$ is said to be uniformly integrable if the following two conditions satisfies
(1) $sup_\alpha\int_{\Omega}|f|d\nu<\infty$
(2) $\lim_{\nu(A)\to0}\int_{A}|f|d\nu$=0
So I understood these two conditions and also I generated some examples to understand them but one thing I want to know besides this is "What is the meaning of Uniform integrability in simple language" like if I choose my $\Omega=R$ then I know we can visualize it graphically somehow but I am finding it difficult to visualize. If someone please help me to visualize this definition that will be a great help.Thanks

Comment: the meaning in simple language is conditions (1) and (2). Sorry...

Comment: Not so sure if these helps but why not try. Uniform integrability is equivalent to weak relative compactness in $L^1$; this result is called Dunford-Pettis theorem. So you can think it as some form of compactness criterion. Indeed, uniform integrability prevents things from "escaping to infinifty" in some sense if you think about it.

Comment: Another thing is its equivalence with (uniform) equicontinuity as functions on the sigma algebra. The measure $\nu$ naturally gives a topology (more precisely, a *uniformity*) to the sigma algebra, and $L^1$ functions have natural identification to absolutely continuous measures via Radon-Nikodym theorem. Then a collection of $L^1$ functions is uniformly integrable if and only if the corresponding measures are (uniformly) equicontinuous as functions on the sigma algebra.

Comment: Recall that equicontinuity is intimately related to compactness via Arzela-Ascoli theorem, so again we can view uniform integrability as some form of compactness condition.